# cvCreateMat in OpenCV 4.0

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, shared-ptr

I recently upgraded my system to OpenCV 4.0 and I am having trouble updating some of my other code to be compatible. I am trying to create a shared pointer of cv:Mat with cvCreateMat. This is what I have originally for OpenCV 3.4. Does anybody know how to do this in 4.0?

```
cv::Ptr<CvMat> _pts(cvCreateMat(4, 4, CV_32FC2));
```

Comment: `cvCreateMat` isn't C++, it's the old (deprecated) C API. Use one of the [Mat constructors](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html).

Comment: I don't think CvMat exists on opencv 4.0, but you can use cv::Ptr<cv::Mat> _pts(new cv::Mat(4, 4, CV_32FC2)) instead.

Comment: You can, however, add this include: 

#include <opencv2/core/core_c.h>

Answer (score 0):

From the [OpenCV documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.10/da/d58/deprecated.html):

> `CvMat` is now obsolete; consider using `Mat` instead.